# html radio check box with all same value

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

I have something like this:

```
form.innerHTML='<form name="reg" >
    Register:<br/>User Name: <input name="un"><br/>
    Password: <input name="pw" type="password"><br/>
    E-mail: <input type="email" name="email" ><br/> 
    Sex:<br/><input type="radio" id="sxf" name="sex" value="f"> <label for =  "sxf">Female</label><br/>
             <input type="radio" id="sxm" name="sex" value="m" checked = "checked" >
             <label for = "sxm">Male</label><br/>
             <input type="button" value="Register" onClick="accnew()"> 
</form>';
```

However, when I sent the form to MYSQL, all returned "f", but there's different value, isn't it? when I alert it with js, it also gave me all "f"s

EDIT:
accnew() js method:

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else{
var xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{..................
xmlhttp.open("GET","new_acc.php?un="+un+"&pw="+pw+"&email="+em+"&group1="+$('[name=sex]').val(),true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

just a xmlHTTPrequest. I tried to use jquery but it didn't work either

Comment: What does the following PHP code display when submitting the form? `print_r($_GET);`

Comment: Note that you are inserting a `form` tag into the form DOM element.

Comment: can you post the content off the accnew js method ?

Comment: @Alexander Ho - Check my updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using $('[name=sex]').val() jquery return the first found object with the selector provided; so you still have 'f' as value returned

You must change your selector by adding a ':checked' (see http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/ ) selector as :

```
      $('input:checked[name="sex"]').val()
```

Anas

Comment: however, when i just use document.form.whatever, it also returns 'f', s it the same explanation

Answer (score -1):

There are several problems with the XHTML of your output code.  (Note that I'm assuming you're intending the output to be XHTML since your break tags are coded as `<br/>`.)

1. You have spaces where they aren't allowed.
2. Input type of "email" is only valid in HTML5.  May not be a problem for you, but just be aware.

So, try something like this...

```
form.innerHTML='<form name="reg" action="page.html" method="get">Register:<br/>User Name: <input name="un" /><br/>Password: <input name="pw" type="password" /><br/>E-mail: <input type="text" name="email" /><br/> Sex:<br/><input type="radio" id="sxf" name="sex" value="f" /><label for="sxf">Female</label><br/><input type="radio" id="sxm" name="sex" value="m" checked="checked" /><label for="sxm">Male</label><br/><input type="submit" value="Register" /> </form>';
```

Comment: Oh, and you'll need to add your javascript onclick back to the submit button.  I replaced with with a typical submit button for testing.

Comment: Oh.. and before someone trolls my answer.. yes, I realize that 'type="email"' would degrade gracefully to a typical textbox in a browser that doesn't support the email type.

Comment: All new input types in HTML5 fall back to "text" if they are not supported by the browser. There is no need to change the markup for different browsers

Comment: Nearly five years later, and I see the funniest reply I've ever received on SO.  LMAO.  Thanks @qsheets.

Answer (score -1):

As Shikyo suggested, you are inserting a  tag inside the HTML of a  tag, so it should result in something like this:

```
<form>
<form name="reg"  >Register:
```

Of course this won't work, you should get the parent tag that contains the form and then do:

```
parent_of_form.innerHTML='
<form name="reg" method="POST" action="somewhere.php" onsubmit="return accnew()">
Register:<br/>
User Name: <input name="un"/><br/>
Password: <input name="pw" type="password"/><br/>
E-mail: <input type="email" name="email" /><br/> 
Sex:<br/>
<input type="radio" id="sxf" name="sex" value="f"/> Female<br/>
<input type="radio" id="sxm" name="sex" value="m" CHECKED/>Male<br/>
<input type="submit" value="Register"/> 
</form>';
```

I have changed some tags here:

1- I assumed you want to validate the form with the accnew() function, so I added the "onsubmit" to the form and changed the Register button to a submit button. This will ensure that you return 'true' with the accnew() function before submiting the form.

2- The label tags aren't really needed, so I removed them, but if you want to keep them that's fine.

3- the checked="checked" won't work, you have to add CHECKED to the end of the input tag.